# Trouble stripping down string values within a column, then converting it to an integer in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, int

Greetings Stack Overflow Community!

I am trying to perform a seemingly simple operation, but it is turning out to be quite frustrating for me!

Allow me to explain in simple terms: I have this dataframe...

```
print(dfx)

Select a BW Speed
0               50 Mb
1              100 Mb
2              100 Mb
3               50 Mb
4               50 Mb
```

I need a piece of code that will manipulate only the second column by 1)Striping out the space and the "Mb" characters, then 2)convert this into an Int (or a float, even) so that I can perform further comparisons/analysis down the line. I basically just want the numerical part of the data, nothing else!

This is an example of what it should look like ideally:

```
print(dfx)

Select a BW Speed
0               50
1              100
2              100
3               50
4               50
```

This is my latest attempt:

```
 dfx ['Select a BW Speed']= dfx['Select a BW Speed'].str.replace(r'\D', '').astype(int)
```

Which results in this error....

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Best,

-Christopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from trying to cast to `int` `NaN` values. Hence you need `pd.to_numeric` to handle those cases. Here's a way using panda's `str` accessor methods:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Select a BW Speed'].str.split().str[0], errors='coerce')

0     50
1    100
2    100
3     50
4     50
Name: Select a BW Speed, dtype: int64
```

---

Or using your own approach:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Select a BW Speed'].str.replace(r'\D', ''), errors='coerce')
```